# Python: Printing in the same exact spot using \r not working?

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to print in the exact same spot:

```
for i in range(10):
    print("ok\r"),
```

However, this prints 10 oks in different lines:

```
ok
ok
...
```

I tried putting the \r in the front of the string as well. In this case, I get a blank line then 10 oks:

```
[blank]
ok
ok
...
```

I also tried the following

```
import sys

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write('ok\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

But I get the same exact thing. I am on Python 2.7 in pyscripter, what am I doing wrong? I also tried in IDLE, and there 'okokokokokokokokokok' is the result when \r is on the end, and ' ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok' is the result when it is in the front.

Edit: I am on windows 7

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: pyscripter probably does something fancy with the console output and isn't honoring the `\r` or you are on windows where it goes wrong

Comment: probably you mean `\b` not `\r`; and if that is the case you should do `, end=''`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `print` function is back-ported to py2.7: `from __future__ import print_function`, so you can still use `, end=''`

Comment: I am on windows, does that mean \r and \b won't work?

Comment: @JakobBowyer I get the same issue on IDLE, @PadraicCunningham I tried importing from `__future__` and then using `print('ok\r',end='')` but still get 10 oks in a row.

Comment: I know for sure that IDLE doesn't respect cursor movement sequences (like `\r` and `\b`). I don't know if pyscripter does. Have you tried your code in the plain old python shell in a CMD window?

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code, it works on ubuntu, I added a time.sleep call so you can see  what is actually happening:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(str(i),end='\r')
    time.sleep(.4)
```

Comment: Important:it won't work unless you add at the top of the file: `from __future__ import print_function` (unless you're using Python3, that is)

Answer (score 0):

For **python 2**:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys

for i in range(10):
    print('ok', end="\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Per a [gist](https://gist.github.com/alfasin/8c4cf0733164d28a4b7c) I wrote a while ago.

For **python 3**, no need for the following line:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: thanks for the post. I get the following: http://i.imgur.com/0PwxImb.png (a bunch of oks with a strange symbol in between)

Comment: I also get the same thing in the image above with `print "ok\b" * 10`

Comment: @casandra you can either use a whitespace or `\t` - if I understand your requirement correctly. Can you post the requested output ?

Comment: the desired output would be one 'ok' since I just want to print in the same exact spot. (I am doing this to create a progress bar, that shows percent completion of a script).

Comment: If you're trying to do this in the REPL it won't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945813/python-printing-in-the-same-exact-spot-using-r-not-working

Comment: @BSpiros so it will only work in command line? Also, your link links to this question.

Comment: oops. sorry, I'll fix the link. My understanding is that \r will not work in the interactive interpreter.